# DIV position adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the click of the left (green) DIV, I want to display a fourth DIV:

```
var a = document.getElementById("myDropdown")
var b = document.getElementById("begueradj")
b.addEventListener("click", func)
function func() {
    var c = a.getAttribute("class")
    console.log(c)
    if(c == "dropdown-content") {
        a.setAttribute("class", "hide")
    }else {
        a.setAttribute("class", "dropdown-content")
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I want to push the gray DIV down and left:

- To the left so that it gets aligned with the green DIV
- Down so that it starts when the first row formed by the green and blue DIVs end.

Note : the `min-height` I set in `.row` is variable.

[**JS Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/Billal_BEGUERADJ/5gc5nrec/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS settings for `.dropdown-content` like this (adjust the `min-width` as you like):

```
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 0 10px;
    left: 8px;
    top: 47px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czznxhbz/

Comment: well, you can adjust all these values as you need them: top, left, padding, width or min-width...

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, all you have to do is move your html around. This way your menu will always be below the top divs and be hidden till you need it.

```
<div class = "col-2"> 
        <div id = "begueradj"> Press</div>

    </div>
    <div class = "col-10" align-text = "right" > Right DIV</div>
</div>
<div id = "myDropdown" class = "dropdown-content">
            <p>Home</p>
            <p>About</p>
            <p>Contact</p>
        </div>

 <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-12">
    Nulla cursus commodo placerat. Mauris id arcu congue, rho 
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In that case you can always make the position of your "myDropDown" absolute and get the computed height of your top row to allow for adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/5gc5nrec/15/

---

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-2 {width: 16.66%; background-color : #4CAF50 ; color : white; text-align : left; padding : 10px;position:relative;height:60px;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%; background-color : blue; color : white; text-align : right;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}


[class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    }

.row{
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display : flex;
        min-height : 60px;
}
/* Responsive */
#begueradj{height:60px;}

.dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        float : left;
        background-color: gray;
    width : 100%;
    left:0;
    top:60px;
}

.hide { display: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to keep the width of the gray div to 50%

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to line it up how you specified, then this should work:

```
.dropdown-content {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   float : left;
   background-color: gray;
   width : 50%;
   left:8px;
   top:68px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you have included the `.drop-down` inside the `.col-2` div, for which you have given a `padding: 10px`. You need to make the earlier one out the `.col-2` div and give it a `margin-top` of 60px, as you put the min-height for `.row` to be 60px.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magician03/ye253m7x/2/)

Comment: It is adjusted as far as I can see, they both( green and grey divs) have zero `padding-left` .

Answer (score 1):

Change your css for dropdown-content

Take a look: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gc5nrec/16/)

```css
.dropdown-content p{
   padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

#begueradj{
   padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```